# How to interact with user (for example a confirm dialog) during a long running server action?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 application. There is a specific action which processes an uploaded large CSV file, and sometimes it needs additional information from the user during this task. For example at row 5, the software needs to show a confirm to the user it he really wants to do something with it, etc. In Winforms environment this was very easy, however I have no idea how I could implement the same on the web.

I would prefer a synchronous way, so that the server thread would be blocked until the confirmation. Otherwise I feel I would have to completely rewrite the logic.

What makes things even more difficoult, is that I would not only need the simple confirmation, but also time to time there can be more complex choices for the user, which can't be implemented synchronously on the client side (only the native simple `confirm` is synchronous AFAIK).

Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated, a complete short guide even more.

EXAMPLE

In this example the client calls a method which returns the numbers `0, 1, 2, ..., 99, 100`. Let's say our users potentially hate the numbers which are dividable by 5. We need to implement a feature which allows the users to exclude these numbers if they whish so. Users don't like to plan for the future, so they wish to choose wether they like such a number or not in real time as the processing happens.

```
[Controller]

public enum ConfirmResult {
  Yes = 0,
  No = 1,
  YesToAll = 2,
  NoToAll = 3
}

...

public JsonResult SomeProcessingAction() {
  var result = new List<int>();
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i%5==0) {
      // sketch implementation for example purposes
      if (Confirm(string.Format("The number {0} is dividable by 5. Are you sure you want to include it?", i) == ConfirmResult.No)
        continue;
    }
    result.Add(i);
  }
  return Json(result);
}

public ConfirmResult Confirm(string message) {
  // ... show confirm message on client-side and block until the response comes back... or anything else 
}


[Javascript]
// sketch...
$.post('mycontroller/someprocessing', function(result) {
  $('#results').text("Your final numbers: " + result.join(', '));
});
```

Comment: I know google spreadsheet can do that, but I'm clueless of other solution

Comment: I would look at SignalR, if you post some of your view code and controller code I can post an example

Comment: I agree with @JamieRees, avoid synchronous way, use signalR

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've added a very simple example, but probably enough for demonstration.

Comment: You're almost certainly going to want to build that functionality such that the state of the task can be described, stored, and resumed later.  For example, if a user starts the long running task and walks off, then receives an input prompt, you'd be left with locked up resources potentially indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I threw together an example and put it up on github for you to take a look at.
[MVC5 long running input-required example](https://github.com/zachdsawyer/InputRequiredExample).

Please note, this is not necessarily the best way to design this. It's my initial approach without a lot of thought. There probably are more flexible or complex, or more recommended patterns.

Basically it just stores the state of a Job in the database (using Entity Framework in the example) whenever it changes.
Persisting to disk or database has definite advantages over some type of long running "synchronous" methods.

- It does not lock up resources while waiting for input
- It safeguards against data loss in case of crashes or server timeouts
- It allows flexibility in case you want to run or resume in a scaled out environment, or on a completely different server (e.g. a non-front-facing VM).
- It allows better management of currently running jobs.

For this example, I chose not to use Signalr because it wouldn't add significant value. In the case of long running jobs (say, 5+ minutes), sub-second responses are not going to add to the user experience.  I would recommend simply polling from javascript every 1-2 seconds.  Much simpler.

Note that some of the code is quite hackish; for example, having the Input fields duplicated on the ResumableJobState table.

The flow might look something like this,

- upload file > returns filename // not impl in my example
- call StartJob(filename) > returns (Json)Job
- Poll GetJobState(jobId) > returns (Json)Job
- If (Json)Job.RequiredInputType is populated, show the user an appropriate form to post input back
- Call PostInput with the correct type of input from the appropriate form
- Job will resume

Here's a dump of the main JobController.

```
public class JobController : Controller
{
    private Context _context;
    private JobinatorService _jobinatorService;
    public JobController()
    {
        _context = new Context();
        _jobinatorService = new JobinatorService(_context);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ActiveJobs = _context.LongRunningJobs.Where(t => t.State != "Completed").ToList();//TODO, filter by logged in User
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult StartJob(string filename)//or maybe you've already uploaded and have a fileId instead
    {
        var jobState = new ResumableJobState
        {
            CurrentIteration = 0,
            InputFile = filename,
            OutputFile = filename + "_output.csv"
        };

        var job = new LongRunningJob
        {
            State = "Running",
            ResumableJobState = jobState
        };

        _context.ResumableJobStates.Add(jobState);
        _context.LongRunningJobs.Add(job);
        var result = _context.SaveChanges();
        if (result == 0) throw new Exception("Error saving to database");

        _jobinatorService.StartOrResume(job);

        return Json(job);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetJobState(int jobId)
    {
        var job = _context.LongRunningJobs.Include("ResumableJobState.RequiredInputType").FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == jobId);
        if (job == null)
            throw new HttpException(404, "No job found with that Id");
        return Json(job, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostInput(int jobId, RequiredInputType userInput)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            throw new HttpException(500, "Bad input");

        var job = _context.LongRunningJobs.Include("ResumableJobState.RequiredInputType").FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == jobId);
        job.ResumableJobState.BoolInput = userInput.BoolValue;
        job.ResumableJobState.IntInput = userInput.IntValue;
        job.ResumableJobState.FloatInput = userInput.FloatValue;
        job.ResumableJobState.StringInput = userInput.StringValue;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        if (job == null)
            throw new HttpException(404, "No job found with that Id");

        if (userInput.InputName == job.ResumableJobState.RequiredInputType.InputName)//Do some checks to see if they provided input matching the requirements
            _jobinatorService.StartOrResume(job);
        //TODO have the jobinator return the State after it's resumed, otherwise we need another Get to check the state. 
        return Json(job);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stuff this in it's own service.  This way, you could use it in other places; for example starting scheduled jobs from a cron job
    /// </summary>
    public class JobinatorService//Ideally use Dependency Injection, or something good practicey to get an instance of this
    {
        private Context _context = new Context();
        private string _filePath = "";
        public JobinatorService(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString() + "/";
        }

        public void StartOrResume(LongRunningJob job)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var inputFile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(_filePath + job.ResumableJobState.InputFile))
                using (var outputFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(_filePath + job.ResumableJobState.OutputFile))
                {
                    inputFile.Position = job.ResumableJobState.CurrentIteration;
                    for (int i = (int)inputFile.Position; i < inputFile.Length; i++)//casting long to int, what could possibly go wrong?
                    {

                        if (job.State == "Input Required" && job.ResumableJobState.RequiredInputType != null)
                        {//We needed input and received it
                            //You might want to do a switch..case on the various inputs, and branch into different functions

                            if (job.ResumableJobState.RequiredInputType.InputName == "6*7")
                                if (job.ResumableJobState.RequiredInputType.IntValue.Value == 42)
                                    break;//Pass Go, collect 42 dollars;
                        }
                        outputFile.WriteByte((byte)inputFile.ReadByte());//Don't try this at home!

                        job.ResumableJobState.CurrentIteration = i;//or row, or line, or however you delimit processing
                        job.ResumableJobState.InputFileBufferReadPosition = inputFile.Position;//or something

                        if (i % 7 == 0)
                            job.ResumableJobState.RequiredInputType = _context.RequiredInputTypes.First(t => t.InputName == "Row 7 Input");
                        if (i % 42 == 0)
                            job.ResumableJobState.RequiredInputType = _context.RequiredInputTypes.First(t => t.InputName == "6*7");

                        if (job.ResumableJobState.RequiredInputType != null)
                            job.State = "Input Required";
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                        if (job.State != "Running")
                            return;
                    }
                    job.State = "Completed";
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            });
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but there are quite a few bad practices in here e.g. Having your Db context in your controllers. It's seems very over complex for the requirements, it might be worth looking at `Hangfire.io`. But a good answer so you deserve an upvote.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. I was thinking about solutions like this, but while I like your idea, this means I have to completely rewrite the already existing processing code (a WinForms application had this module, where the interaction was abstracted to a simple interface, but expected a synchrnous reply). However, it seems to be worth it, because the web is so much different in this particular case than desktop.

Comment: @JamieRees, there are indeed bad practices galore, as it was not meant to showcase good general practices, but the core pause/resume idea.   Regarding complexity, I disagree though. The web simply _is_ _not_ synchronous. Attempting to coerce it so, or make it appear so is not just swimming upstream, it's swimming up a waterfall.  Solutions that hold/block resources while waiting on users are simply nonviable in most web scenarios